# Intern: How to set Selenium capability to accept ssl certificates using intern 3.0 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, intern

I have the following config but it does not seem to work.
The request is logged to the proxy server but I do not get response back. There is an alert generated on the proxy re. unknown certificate:

```
  capabilities: { 
     "selenium-version": "2.45.0",
      proxy: {
          proxyType: "manual ", // manual or autodetect
          httpProxy: "some.valid.ip.addr:8083",
          noProxy: "http://localhost:9000/"
     }
      ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: true //'acceptSslCerts';
  }
```

Am I using the right setting for ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS?

Comment: I am guessing you might need to point to the right certificate?. try removing only the ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS key and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for your response. But it does not work. The proxy I am trying to use is for the ZAP / BurpSuite.